# How to dynamically add select menu option in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone know if there is a simple solution to dynamically adding new options to a select menu in a form in Rails?

The Dynamic Forms railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms) is focused on dynamically filtering a second selet menu based on the selection made in another select menu which is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a solution where the form contains only one select menu and new options can be added to it on the form.

I feel the solution may be similar to that touched upon in the Nested Model Form railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) but in that example the form must be submitted before the values are updated in the database. I would like the user to be able to add a new select menu option and then continue with the rest of the form before submitting it.

At this stage I would also like to avoid using the railscast jquery autocomplete solution as this uses a text field rather than a select menu.

Currently I see the solution as having a "Add New" button next to the select menu. When the button is clicked a Modal is opened that allows the user to enter the new select menu option and then save (update the database), the modal is closed and the form is updated. I'm just wondering whether an existing elegant solution is already out there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I haven't created any code to implement this yet but here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @other, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>  
<fieldset>
  <%= f.error_notification %>           
  <%= f.association :other_type, :include_blank => false %>      
  <%= f.input :cost%>
  <%= f.input :invoice %>             
  <%= f.input :notes, :input_html => {:class => "row-fluid"} %>
<%= f.error :base %>
<div id="eze_form_actions" class="form-actions">
  <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to 'Cancel', others_path, :class => 'btn' %>
</div>
</fieldset>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: Post your code as well

Comment: With some javascript magic you can make it look exactly like dynamic forms and all those gems ...

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit of a newbie so if there is no existing solution then that means I've got a bit of reading to do on how to implement it with javascript. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to this in our CMS for categories, users can easily add a new category and we POST to the server, which responds with HTML (render through a partial) and we inject it into our set of checkboxes. You can easily replicate this for your purposes:

To get this to work, you'll need your a form, an endpoint and some javascript:

**Form**

Not sure what you're form will include, but use regular form helpers and make sure the form is set to `remote: true`.

**End Point**

Your endpoint should render a partial, which should only contain the html for the .. which we'll render to a string and pass back to the front-end to be added.

```
def endpoint
  # create your new model with the params
  @model = Model.create(some: attribute)
  if @model.errors.empty and @model.save
    render json: { html: render_to_string(partial: "path/to/partial", locals: { model: @model })
  end
end
```

** JavaScript **

```
$(form)
  .bind('ajax:success', function(data, status) {
    $(select).append(status.html)
  })
```

status.html should be something like `<option>...</option>` and so we just append to our select.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help. I have never heard of an endpoint before and the best definition I could find was "A Rack endpoint is just an application that adheres to the Rack spec". Where in my project do I put my endpoint? Do you have an example up on GitHub?

Comment: And endpoint is just a route, like `/path/to/endpoint` which you post your data to. In your case, it's whatever this renders to `simple_form_for @other`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm trying my best to keep up here. Doesn't my form need to remain unchanged so I can still submit it as normal to add a new item, etc. Does the select menu submit its own form?